# "Nothing" interpreter/compiler

Tags: c++, interpreter

This is an implementation of the [**Nothing**](http://www.turtle.dds.nl/nothing/) programming language. The language spec is as follows:

> ## Design philosophy
>
> In the current software industry focus lays on solving complex
>   problems by using complicated algorithms. The language "Nothing" was
>   created to shift this focus from complex problems towards the
>   expectations of the programmer and the user. This way even the most
>   complicated programming challenges swiftly disappear as if they never
>   have existed before. Basically, the main strengths of the language
>   "Nothing" are:
>
> - to create bug-free and portable software https://esolangs.org/wiki/Nothing
> - to shift focus from complex technical solutions towards the expectation of the programmers and users
>
> ## Program structure
>
> Nothing has a very simple and straightforward structure. It is a
>   typeless language which does not use any of the known programming
>   constructs like loops, choices and the like. It is the only language
>   which can be considered 1GL, 2GL, 3GL, 4GL and 5GL all at the same
>   time.

What I would like to know:

- Does my program conform to the language specs?
- Does it follow the design philosophy?
- Readability, performance, etc. Any improvements welcome

Source code:

```
/*
 * A 'Nothing' compiler
 * <http://www.turtle.dds.nl/nothing/>
 * September 2010, RoPe Development Inc.
 *
 * Author: authorname
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string> // std::char_traits<char>::eof

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: no input files\n";
        std::cerr << "compilation terminated.";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::ifstream program(argv[1]);

    if (!program)
    {
        std::cerr << "nothing: error: " << argv[1] << ": No such file or directory\n";
        std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: no input files\n";
        std::cerr << "compilation terminated.";        
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (program.peek() != std::char_traits<char>::eof())
    {
        std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: program is not empty\n";
        std::cerr << "compilation terminated.";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example:

```
# bash
$ touch helloworld.not
$ ./nothing helloworld.not
$
```

Comment: Why not print a newline at the end of all error messages?

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5947/9357).

Comment: I'm confused. You tagged this question as [tag:compiler], yet it doesn't generate an executable. Is it really an [tag:interpreter]?

Comment: @200_success I can't modify the question now. I could follow the reference implementation and use `chmod` from `sys/stat.h` on an empty file.

Comment: @200_success I thought about using a library to create ELF files...but then my compiler wouldn't be so portable anymore. :|

Comment: @user82302 You can modify the question. There is a small button underneath your question labeled "edit". I've already gone ahead and done that for you.

Answer (score 8):

This line here:

> ```
> return EXIT_SUCCESS
> ```

Is equivalent to this:

```
return 0;
```

Which is automatically inserted by the compiler if it isn't found. In short, `return EXIT_SUCCESS` can be removed.

In addition, a few of your error messages don't include a newline at the end, as seen in this line here, and two other places:

> ```
> std::cerr << "compilation terminated.";
> ```

I'd just add a newline to the end of the output string to not annoy the user when the program completes/fails, like this:

```
std::cerr << "compilation terminated.\n";
```

Instead of requiring the user to provide a file in the command line arguments, you can just do, well, nothing. This is the language Nothing after all. This means that this piece of code here:

> ```
> if (argc < 2)
> {
>     std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: no input files\n";
>     std::cerr << "compilation terminated.";
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
> }
> ```

Can just become this:

```
if (argc < 2)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Other than those two nitpicks, there really isn't much else for me to review here. As far as I can tell, you've followed the language specification just fine, and produced some readable code.

Comment: In C++, it is often common to use `<< "message" << endl;` to add a line break to the code.

Comment: @SirPython `std::endl` flushes the output buffer, and `"\n"` doesn't. I'm assuming the OP doesn't want that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @SirPython It's redundant because I'm using `std::cerr`

Answer (score 5):

- Don't hardcode the error message. Failure to open a stream is not necessarily due to `no such file or directory`; you may have insufficient privileges, for example. Use `perror()`.
- There is no reason to compile just one file at a time.
- There's no reason to restrict the program to files on disk. It would be nice to be able to use it in pipeline.
- The `--silent` option to suppress error messages is always nice to have.
- Localization is a must! Not everybody reads English.
- `help` is missing.
- For more details, visit [GNU Hello World](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/) page.

Comment: … or [use `strerror()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17338934/1157100).

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer**: I know **Nothing** about C++

Inside the `!program` if, you seem to have forgotten this line:

```
std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: no input files\n";
```

Which is also present on the `if (argc < 2)` block. Probably a copy-paste mistake?

---

Since your error messages are almost always the same, you could make a function to show the error message. Like this:

```
void show_error(std::string message)
{
    std::cerr << "nothing: fatal error: " << message << "\n";
    std::cerr << "compilation terminated.\n";
}
```

---

You have the following line:

```
std::ifstream program(argv[1]);
```

The first time I read this, I though: Why is he making a new program? But [after some teaching](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23754172#23754172), I've found out it is an object.

The `if (!program)` block really confused me. I couldn't get why you were checking if there isn't a program.

Since this is a compiler/interpreter, you need code. My suggestion: rename it to `code` or `file`. Both would be so much obvious than `program`. It isn't a bad name! It just isn't the best one.

Comment: I would take that second recommendation one step further by exiting out of the application with an `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: @SirPython That's completelly outside my severelly limited knowledge, but a really good idea. I though about it but gave up.